# Distributing pip packages that have non-pypi dependencies

Tags: python, installation, pypi

So I have a PyPi package that has a few PyPi dependencies. So far, it's all good. Now I'm planning on adding a feature that requires a dependancy that isn't on PyPi, how would I go about doing this?

Can I package and install the dependancy with it? Can I have the install script run a set of commands? Or will I have to either tell the users to install it or have it install when the actual program runs?

This is a possible duplicate but the others did not answer my question.